# Can't use std::apply on std::array

Tags: c++, arrays, apply

I am trying to apply a lambda to the elements of an std::array.

```
    std::array<int, 4> fixIndices = {1, 60, 127, 187};

    std::apply(
        [](int id) {
            std::cout << id;
        },
        fixIndices);
```

However, this simple code doesn't compile

```
/usr/lib/gcc/x86_64-pc-linux-gnu/10.3.0/include/c++/tuple:1727:27: error: no matching function for call to ‘__invoke(****)::<lambda(int)>, int&, int&, int&, int&)’
 1727 |       return std::__invoke(std::forward<_Fn>(__f),
      |              ~~~~~~~~~~~~~^~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
 1728 |       std::get<_Idx>(std::forward<_Tuple>(__t))...);
```

What am I missing?

Answer (score 6):

[`std::apply`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/utility/apply) forwards the arguments contained in the tuple(-like) to the callable `f`, so your lambda should be

```
std::array<int, 4> fixIndices = {1, 60, 127, 187};
std::apply(
  [](auto... ids) {
     ((std::cout << ids << " "), ...);
  }, 
  fixIndices);
```

But for `std::array`, if you want to iterate over its elements, a range-based for loop is an easier option.

Answer (score 5):

[`std::apply`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/utility/apply) is to call a callable with parameters given as a tuple. For example you can call some

```
auto f = [](int a,double b,char c) {}
```

with a `std::tuple<int,double,char>`. Note that `std::array` is tuple-like, ie you could use your array to call a callable that expects `4` parameters.

However, here you do not need `std::apply`. You can use a loop:

```
std::array<int, 4> fixIndices = {1, 60, 127, 187};
auto f = [](int id) { std::cout << id;};
for (const auto& id : fixIndices) f(id);
```

Or closer to your code via `for_each`:

```
std::for_each(fixIndices.begin(),fixIndices.end(), [](int id) { std::cout << id; });
```

Comment: You could also use `std::ranges::for_each` to avoid the `begin()` and `end()` calls if you happen to have a C++20 compiler.

Comment: Aside: you *can* call `std::apply` with a `std::array<T, N>` argument, if you have a function that accepts `N` arguments that implicitly convert from `T`, because `std::array` is tuple-like

Comment: Oh, I thought std::apply was calling the predicate on each parameter!

Comment: @jjcasmar thats what `for_each` does already. I also have to look up `std::apply` again everytime i see it ;)

Comment: @463035818_is_not_a_number yeah. The issue is that I though std::apply was meant to call a predicate on each element of a tuple, and by extension, it could be also used for std::array without the need to use iterators, as if it was a range. My bad, I misunderstood how std::apply is designed!